# git/bitbucket pushed a reference rather than the folder

Tags: git, composer-php

I apologize if this is a stupid question. I can't find the words to describe it to google.

I'm using BitBucket (with git). I see in BitBucket that some folders are missing. They simply show up as what I assume is a reference (hash) to a commit or something. Could you explain to me what I'm looking at?

These are non-clickable 'folders'.

[image: No twig for you]
[image: Another empty folder]

(I understand saving the vendor folder (composer) to VCS is unnecessary/unwanted/bad practice, I promise I have really good reasons in this case.)

All other folders (Including the folder for `SwiftMailer` which is also inside `vendor`) have been pushed normally.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders which were not pushed are themselves git repositories.
You can confirm this by verifying there is a .git folder in each of them.
The sha1 you see in Bitbucket is the reference of the commit of the subproject used by your project.

If you want to store the content of these folders in Bitbucket, you just have to delete the .git subdirectory in these folders. But It would not encourage you to do it, as, like you said, it's a bad practice ^^

Comment: Wow, thank you! That seems to be the case. How come some packages don't include the `.git` folder? e.g. SwiftMailer doesn't have a .git folder even tho it's a package from composer and there's a `.gitignore` file implying the use of git.

Comment: Did you install oall of the packages through composer? Or did you install some of them by doing a git clone?

Comment: I installed all of them through composer.